# PHP static variable inside method with assignment to 0 + increment how is this work?

Tags: php, oop, static

```
<?php
trait Counter {
    public function inc() {
        static $c = 0;
        $c = $c + 1;
        echo "$c\n";
    }
}

class C1 {
    use Counter;
}

class C2 {
    use Counter;
}

$o = new C1(); 
$o->inc(); // echo 1
$o->inc(); // echo 2
$o->inc(); // echo 3
?>
```

How is this thing work?

In method `inc` what does really do `static $c = 0;` ? I have seen so far only making static variable as property in class not method like `public static $c = 0;` and not `static $c = 0;` in class's method.

What does this really do? This is asigning `$c` to `0` in the beginning of this method, so why is this really incrementing?

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Comment: @iainn thank you :)

Comment: I should probably add, this is generally not great practice. Using a class member variable is a much cleaner approach.